# external php echo/print_r not outputting values to browser

Tags: php, html, forms, post, echo

This is code is saved in a file called form.php

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form acion = "insert.php" method = "POST">
        UserName:<br> <input type = "text" name = "uname"/><br>
        Password:<br><input type = "password" name = "pswd"/><br>
        First Name:<br><input type = "text" name = "fname"/><br>
        Last Name:<br><input type = "text" name = "lname"/><br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "submit"/>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

This code is saved in a file called insert.php in the same folder (xampp/htdocs/aform)

```
<?php
    echo "hello world";

    $uname = $_POST['uname'];

    print_r($_POST['uname']);

    $pass = $_POST['pswd'];
    $first = $_POST['fname'];
    $last = $_POST['lname'];

    print_r($_POST['uname']);
    echo $uname;

?>
```

None of the echo or print_r statements return anything to the browser after the submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just correct this (you have a missing 't'):

```
<form acion = "insert.php" method = "POST">
```

To:

```
<form action = "insert.php" method = "POST">
```

Comment: insert.php is missing if(isset($_POST['submit')){}

Comment: Oh my F**king god. Thank you. Sorry, should have copped that. Feeling quite sheepish

Comment: @0_insomniac_0 It's ok! We all did it ;)

Comment: @cpt-crunchy That's only needed if the same script is used for displaying and processing the form. It's not needed for a script that's only run when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Barmar. Good to know.